# Zend\Mail, Class 'Zend\Mail\Message' not found,

Tags: zend-framework

```
<?php
use Zend\Mail;

$mail = new Mail\Message();
$mail->setBody('This is the text of the email.');
$mail->setFrom('Freeaqingme@example.org', 'Sender\'s name');
$mail->addTo('Matthew@example.com', 'Name of recipient');
$mail->setSubject('TestSubject');

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Sendmail();
$transport->send($mail);
?>
```

the above codes are from the Zend framework official website,the url is 
*http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mail.introduction.html*

When run the above code,there is the following error:
Fatal error: Class 'Zend\Mail\Message' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\1\t1.php on line 5

I've put the Zend Framework in my php.ini file, include_path=".;D:\xampp\php\PEAR;D:\xampp\htdocs\ZendFramework-2.3.3\library"

DO I need to preappend the code "require_once(*)" in the code beginning?

I'm a beginer,hope to receive some detailed answers,it would be best to add what codes.

Thank you !

Comment: lib path is configured, OK. But you need an autoloader to handle classes autoloading or simply, import them manually.

Comment: Your application running properly if you dont use Zend\Mail???

Comment: **Thank you for answering such a simple queston**    1.I'll google the autoloader method in a moment.    2.I've tried importing them manually by using require_once "*",but I've imported many lines,there are still error prompt," a  new class or file not found ",Maybe my import method is not correct.

Answer (score 4):

Check the contents of `composer.json`. Try:

```
composer require zendframework/zend-mail
```

Answer (score 2):

```
composer require zendframework/zend-mail
```

this will solve your problem, but in Magento 2.3.4 they remove \Zend* all class.

Magento add Zend/ classes into **Laminas**.

So try this one

```
$mail = new Laminas\Message()
```

instead of

```
$mail = new Mail\Message();
```